# Numeric value of string and vice versa

Tags: perl

Is there any built-in function (like we have ord for a single character) to convert a string into its equivalent numeric value and vice versa i.e. getting back the string from the equivalent numeric value.

Comment: so, i love perl for this code: `$last_part = '0000'; $last_part++; print $last_part;`

Comment: yes: two examples you need: `$t='0213sadf';
$t++;
print $t;`
and my first example. perl trying convert string to numeric. in first example, it will convert `'0000'` to `0000` and inc `0001`. 
second example, it will convert `'0213sadf'` to `213` and inc `214`.
use `codepad.org` to see results.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the [approach involving `split`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10278888) from [nickisfat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/658663/nickisfat), there's also [`unpack`](http://p3rl.org/unpack):

```
use Encode qw(encode);
my $characters = 'This is my string.';
my $octets = encode 'UTF-8', $characters;
unpack 'C*', $octets
# expression returns qw(84 104 105 115 32 105 115 32 109 121 32 115 116 114 105 110 103 46)
unpack 'H*', $octets
# expression returns '54686973206973206d7920737472696e672e'
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl is dynamically typed. So depending on the context a variable will be treated as a string or as a number. You don't need to explicitly convert.

Comment: Actually I have a script that needs password as input ,but it does not take # as input.Once it finds it does not get connected to the tool that I need to automate.So,I want the password to converd into its numeric equivalent and while passing it to the tool I will convert it back to string

Answer (score 1):

ord will do what you want in Perl also:

```
perl -e '$char = "y"; print ord($char);'
```

You can always use perldoc to check if a function is part of perl, `perldoc -f ord`

Comment: Thanks friend .can you please elaborate?Actullay I don't need to  print it.I need the convert string into  numerical equivalent and then pass it to some subroutine and this subroutine should convert it back to the string.Please help.

Comment: Did you try running the command above? It prints out the numeric value of the character - 'a' = 97, 'b' = 98, ... 'y' = 121'. Is that what you wanted - or did you want to covert between a string like '1021' and a number 1021? In which case, the first poster is right - you just need to use the variable in the right context.

Comment: i want to convert whole string e.g. "ab12c#" into its numeric equivalent and then covert it back to "ab12c#" from the equivalent string.Please help.

Comment: What is the "numeric equivalent of 'abc12#'?

Comment: it should be Numeric value of (a)Numeric value of (b)Numeric value of (c)12Numeric value of (#)

Comment: The char nums for "ab12c#" - 97,98,99,49,50,35

Comment: @gautamkumar Am I understanding correctly? The letters are changed to their numeric value ('a' = 97, 'b' = 98...etc) but '12' stays as 12? If you want the '12' converted to their character values ('1' = 49, '2' = 50) then nickisfat's answer above does that.

Answer (score 1):

Just apply the builtin functions to each char in the string in turn.  The below can probably be made more pretty, but will work:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
use warnings ;

my $string = 'some text' ;
my $num = '115,111,109,101,32,116,101,120,116' ;

strToNum($string) ;
numToStr($num) ;

sub strToNum{
    my $input = shift ;
    local $" = ',' ;
    my @result = map( ord, split(//, $input) ) ;
    print "@result\n" ;
}

sub numToStr{
    my $input = shift ;
    local $" = '' ;
    my @result = map( chr, split(/,/, $input) ) ;
    print "@result\n" ;
}
```

Comment: thanks friend.But you have changed the string into array ,I need it it asd simple scalar variable i.e. $result not @result.Please help.

Comment: I'd recommend that you use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10279185/658663) answer, rather than mine. If you want to use mine for some reason, and need the answer in a scalar you could just do: my $string = "@result" ;

Answer (score 1):

Generally you don't need to convert number and string values, as every scalar automatically updates those when you use it in new context. So when you assign a number to a scalar and later use it in string context, Perl will automatically generate string representation for you.

However, some libraries rely on inspecting scalars to decided how to treat them - as number or as string (Hello, JSON:XS!) There isn't really any clean way to resolve that except to manually reassign number or string value to scalar to wipe "auto generated" part. Use some simple and fast calculation like `$var += 0` to numify or `$var = "$var"` to stringify variables in such cases.